# Set value on basis of multiple conditions Pythonic way

Tags: python-3.x, conditional-statements

I am struggling in finding the best Pythonic way to set value of an object on the  basis of multiple conditions. I am have searched a lot but unable to find solution for too many if statements as they are making my function too long.
I am setting value of `gender` on the basis of different keys that are words present in list of strings.

```
details = ["Women", "Shoes"]

if 'Men' in details:
    gender = 'men'
elif 'Women' in details:
    gender = 'Women'
elif 'girl' in details:
    gender = 'girl'
elif 'boy' in details:
    gender = 'boy'
......
```

How can I make it short?

Comment: I would recommend using a dictionary

Comment: I think there is a typo in your code. Your variable name is detail instead of details. And there is no case switch in python, if you absolutely need it, the elif syntax is the clearer. You might also use a dictionary

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
details = ["Women", "Shoes"]
maps = {"Men": "men", "girl": "girl", "Women": "Women", "boy": "boy"}
for key in maps.keys():
    if key in details:
        gender = maps.get(key, None)
```

Comment: You have some typos in your code, be careful when answerting.

Comment: You have some grammatical errors in your comment. Be careful when commenting.

Comment: Its helpful and make my code short. However to iterate over a _dict_ its better to use `items()` in term of memory cost. Thanks for help.

Comment: Actually,python3 changed the impletation of keys(),iterms() and values().these functions all return an iterator of dict's keys,items or values.see[link](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=keys#dict-views)